# IdnetityServer - get user info in API protected by JWT

Tags: identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I'm using IdentityServer4 and im trying to figure out how to get current userId (guid) in protected API.. Upfront is BFF which proxy all requests to API. When I look in http context there is no user info available.. and `User.isAuthenticated` is always false.

What soud i make to get some user data in that API? Minimal current user UserId to query database..

```
.AddAuthentication("token")  
 .AddJwtBearer("token", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:6666";
            options.MapInboundClaims = false;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidTypes = new[] { "at+jwt" },
                
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            };
        });
```

The `_contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always false

Comment: what does the logs in the API say?

Comment: There are no logs since no error appear the problem was `MapInboundClaims` was not set to `true` and the stuff from access_token did not copied to this context